# debugging LLVM IR with LLDB

Tags: llvm, lldb

I've developed an LLVM front-end generating LLVM IR as the target code from some source-language X. If I extend this front-end to embed debug information within the generated IR, is it possible to use LLDB for debugging my source-language? I mean does lldb support **any** source-language targeting LLVM IR?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to get a DWARF language code and get lldb to recognize it.  If we get some DWARF for an unknown language, we'll just ignore it...

Then with no more support, some things will work, others won't.

If you emit correct line table information, you should be able to map back to your source, and that should get stepping working as well.  Other things start getting hard.

The next hard part is how you are going to tell lldb about your type information.  lldb uses Clang's AST's as internal storage for type information in the debugger.  lldb translates DWARF type information into Clang AST's both for printing local variables (with the `frame variable` command) and for use with the expression parser.

If your language has a type system that looks kinda like C lldb should be able to parse the DWARF for your types.  You'll that plus correct variable information should get `frame variable` working.

The expression parser (i.e. the `expression`, `print` or `po` commands) requires that lldb have a parser for your language.  That can be a pretty big chunk of work.